# Maven surefire and modular JavaFX 11

Tags: java, maven, javafx, maven-surefire-plugin, javafx-11

I have no problem running my project in the IDE or as a packaged jar, but somehow I always get this exception when running with surefire

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
```

The project follows Maven's directory structure. The code I use to load the FXML is

```
Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/App.fxml")
```

Does anyone have any idea what may be the issue? I've tried to google for similar problems but found none. I've also had no luck finding any working example projects that are similar to mine.

Edit 1: Here's the plugin declaration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <threadCount>1</threadCount>
        <printSummary>true</printSummary>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>

        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <glass.platform>Monocle</glass.platform>
            <monocle.platform>Headless</monocle.platform>
            <prism.order>d3d</prism.order>
        </systemPropertyVariables>

        <argLine>
            --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED
            --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=ALL-UNNAMED
        </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Slaw I'm not sure how I would go about that, as I said everything about the project works fine except the maven surefire plugin, maybe I can add the plugin declaration to the question

Comment: I've made a quick test, and it works for me. Are you able to run your app (not the test)? Make sure the path to the FXML file is correct, or both run and test will fail. For instance, try with an absolute path: `"/fxml/App.fxml"`.

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes I can run the app (both in the IDE and as a packaged JAR), it's only the test that fails to run. Can you upload your code to github or somewhere so I can compare between yours and mine?

Comment: It will be better if you posted your code (even better, just a minimal complete and verifiable sample), so anyone can try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: By the way, I'm running `mvn clean compile package` to do the tests. Some plugins forget to copy the resources, so that's why I use `compile.`